# tikz-qtree: adjust sibling distance for only one part of a tree

Tags: tikz-qtree

Is it possible to adjust sibling distance for only one part of a tree using tikz? For instance, if I want to make 6 and 7 farther apart in the following, but leave 3 and 4 alone, is there a way to do that?

[image: sample tree]

I know it's possible to set the `level N/.style={sibling distance = ...}` in the tikzpicture options, but that adjusts it everywhere on that level, instead of just on one part. I'd also like to do it the 'right' way, instead of using `\phantom{XXX}6\phantom{XXX}` or something like that, if that's an option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Tree
        [.1 
            [.2 
                [.3 ]
                [.4 ]
            ]
            [.5 
                [.6 ]
                [.7 ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following code produces something that looks like what I want, but it's obviously a clunky workaround:

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=-0.75cm}]
        \Tree
        [.1 
            [.2 
                [.3 ]
                [.4 ]
            ]
            [.5 
                [.\node[minimum width=20mm]{6}; ]
                [.7 ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe just as hacky, would be `\makebox[20mm]{6}`. Slightly less typing? Since `tikz-qtree` has no direct way of passing TikZ commands to the tree, these are your only options I think.

Comment: If you're not committed to `tikz-qtree` this is a lot simpler in `forest`: you would just add `s sep=10mm` to your node labelled 5.